# JSON.parse(myArray) fails

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

I have an API call which returns data in the following format:

```
[
  {
    "children": null,
    "entityDefinition": {
      "id": 0,
      "version": 0,
      "entityType": "APPLICATION_COMPONENT_NODE",
      "entityId": 8280,
      "prettyToString": null
    },
    "state": "NORMAL",
    "nodesPerformanceStateSummary": null,
    "appServerAgentAvailability": {
      "entityId": 8280,
      "entityType": "APPLICATION_COMPONENT_NODE",
      "latest": true,
      "percentage": 100,
      "metricId": 41540
    },
    "machineAgentAvailability": {
      "entityId": 8280,
      "entityType": "APPLICATION_COMPONENT_NODE",
      "latest": true,
      "percentage": 100,
      "metricId": 41548
    }
  }
],
[
  {
    "children": null,
    "entityDefinition": {
      "id": 0,
      "version": 0,
      "entityType": "APPLICATION_COMPONENT_NODE",
      "entityId": 20552,
      "prettyToString": null
    },
    "state": "NORMAL",
    "nodesPerformanceStateSummary": null,
    "appServerAgentAvailability": {
      "entityId": 20552,
      "entityType": "APPLICATION_COMPONENT_NODE",
      "latest": false,
      "percentage": 0,
      "metricId": 41540
    },
    "machineAgentAvailability": {
      "entityId": 20552,
      "entityType": "APPLICATION_COMPONENT_NODE",
      "latest": true,
      "percentage": 100,
      "metricId": 41548
    }
  }
]
```

When I try to execute

```
JSON.parse(myData).forEach(function(node){
    sails.log.info(node.id);
}
```

it gives me the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 468
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at getListOfAvailableNodes (C:\Users\taaniel.paal\Documents\license-statistics\api\helpers\get-licenses.js:73:14)
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\taaniel.paal\Documents\license-statistics\api\helpers\get-licenses.js:136:30)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\taaniel.paal\Documents\license-statistics\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\taaniel.paal\Documents\license-statistics\node_modules\request\request.js:1161:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\taaniel.paal\Documents\license-statistics\node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1090:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

This works when the array only has one element but when there are more, it fails. Does someone perhaps know a workaround for this? I mean, JSON.parse() should recognize array-type data, or is the issue that there is no root element that contains this array, e.g. { "nodes": ["x", "x", "x"] }? I'm a bit confused and would love some insight from a smarter person :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you already have an object, what are you trying to parse here? `myData.forEach(function(node){
    sails.log.info(node.id);
});`

Comment: Is your _"DB call"_ rolling its own JSON? If so, don't. **Always** use a utility / function / language feature to create a JSON string

Comment: Not sure how I upvote a comment but @Thomas - that was the problem, yep. Everything else works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

This is invalid JSON, you have two root array elements. Server response must be fixed. Currently your have similar to this:

```
[
"first"
],
[
"second"
]
```

Should be:

```
["first", "second"]
```

Comment: You have beaten me by seconds :)

Comment: It happens all the time with me either)